# How to use Angular UI Bootstrap DatePicker Popup with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, datapicker

```
<div class="task-manager_block" ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
    <div class="form_block clearfix">
        <form name="addToDo">
        <input class="add-input" placeholder="I need to..." type="text" name="inputToDo" ng-model="formTodoText" ng-model-instant ng-minlenght ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="40" ng-required="true"/>
        <button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTodo()" ng-disabled="! addToDo.inputToDo.$valid "><h2>Add</h2></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tasks_block" ng-controller="DatepickerPopupCtrl">
        <div class="task_block col-md-3" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <div class="text_block">
                <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
                <p>{{todo.text}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I open a single popup that I clicked on because now all of them are instantly opened independently of what I clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to all the datepickers inside ng-repeat reference the same variable to check open state.

See this.

> is-open="popup1.opened"

You will have to manage this state in a separate object. 
For example,

In controller declare a empty object

> let datePickersStat = {};

then in your HTML, you can use anything as object key as long as it's unique.

> is-open="datePickersStat[todo.id]"

Hope that helps.